# Check-in luggage counter for Indigo flights at Mumbai airport

Tags: luggage, check-in, mumbai, bom, indigo

I have a flight which arrives at Mumbai International Airport and I have to connect to a GoIndigo flight from Terminal 1 (domestic terminal).

Three years ago, when I flew to Mumbai, it had a check-in counter for domestic flights like AirIndia, Jet etc, but not for my GoAir flight. I had to get my luggage and take the shuttle to the domestic airport.

Is there any check-in counter for GoIndigo in Mumbai, so I can just give them my luggage and take airport shuttle to the domestic terminal?

Comment: I haven't found any in T2. But, I might be wrong.  Tweet out to them, the respond very quickly to tweets

Comment: there is no counter, and even they stop shuttle :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check this my self in my trip :).

There is no counter for GoIndigo on internation airport. They have counters for only those airlines, which are operated from that terminal.

One more thing, with GoIndigo, they check your handbags too for 7 KG including your laptop, so please make sure you have only 7 KG for that.